# Based on `left_join` help me join two dataframes + sort the end product? Left_join. R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, left-join

In short, I am having trouble with joining two dataframes. From what i can get done, i am able to 'left_join', but onwards from there, values get tagged to a date, which should be tagged to separate dates. I tried to fix it, but it has driven me to the point that i wrote this. :)

---

My tutorial assignment is:

"Import a data set from internet with periodic data for multiple regions, e.g.

```
     the daily/weekly/monthly number of COVID infections/hospitalizations per 
     continent/country/province.
```

Tidy the data, so the data include

- a variable denoting the period
- a variable denoting the region
- a variable denoting the number

Download a second variable with additional information on the regions, e.g.

- the number of inhabitants

Joint the two data sets on the regions"

I have taken some data from the RIVM:

- [Confirmed covid cases per municipality a day](https://data.rivm.nl/meta/srv/dut/catalog.search#/metadata/5f6bc429-1596-490e-8618-1ed8fd768427)
- [Hospital admissions per municipality a day](https://data.rivm.nl/meta/srv/dut/catalog.search#/metadata/4f4ad069-8f24-4fe8-b2a7-533ef27a899f)

(Datasets can be downloaded at the bottom, csv format)

---

We are instructed to work in Rmarkdown, but I know it's possible to import data easier.

## loaded the following packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
```

## Reading in data

```
Number_day <- read_csv("~/Desktop/UNI/2021-2022/Courses Period 3/Introduction to R/WEEK 7/Tutorials/COVID-19_aantallen_gemeente_per_dag.csv") 

Number_day <- Number_day %>% 
  separate('Version;Date_of_report;Date_of_publication;Municipality_code;Municipality_name;Province;Security_region_code;Security_region_name;Municipal_health_service;ROAZ_region;Total_reported;Deceased', 
           into = c('Version',
                    'Date_of_report',
                    'Date_of_publication',
                    'Municipality_code',
                    'Municipality_name',
                    'Province',
                    'Security_region_code',
                    'Security_region_name',
                    'Municipal_health_service',
                    'ROAZ_region',
                    'Total_reported',
                    'Deceased'),
           sep = ';') %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  na.omit
```

```
Hos_day <- read_csv("~/Desktop/UNI/2021-2022/Courses Period 3/Introduction to R/WEEK 7/Tutorials/COVID-19_ziekenhuisopnames.csv")

Hos_day <- Hos_day %>% 
  separate('Version;Date_of_report;Date_of_statistics;Municipality_code;Municipality_name;Security_region_code;Security_region_name;Hospital_admission_notification;Hospital_admission', 
           into = c('Version',
                    'Date_of_report',
                    'Date_of_statistics',
                    'Municipality_code',
                    'Municipality_name',
                    'Security_region_code',
                    'Security_region_name',
                    'Hospital_admission_notification',
                    'Hospital_admission'),
           sep = ';') %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  na.omit
```

This seems like a lot, but it's just getting the format of the dataframe right + i removed rows containing NA or blank values.

## Selecting variables

There are 280K observations, just to work a bit faster i chose 5K. Also filtered by date; so that each dataset has data from the same period.

```
Number_day <- Number_day %>% 
  select(., "Date_of_publication",
         "Municipality_code",
         "Municipality_name",
         "Deceased") %>% 
  filter(Date_of_publication >= "2020-03-13") %>%
  head(., 5000)

Number_day
```

Giving:

```
## # A tibble: 5,000 x 4
##    Date_of_publication Municipality_code Municipality_name Deceased
##    <chr>               <chr>             <chr>             <chr>   
##  1 2020-03-13          GM0014            Groningen         0       
##  2 2020-03-13          GM0034            Almere            0       
##  3 2020-03-13          GM0037            Stadskanaal       0       
##  4 2020-03-13          GM0047            Veendam           0       
##  5 2020-03-13          GM0050            Zeewolde          0       
##  6 2020-03-13          GM0059            Achtkarspelen     0       
##  7 2020-03-13          GM0060            Ameland           0       
##  8 2020-03-13          GM0072            Harlingen         0       
##  9 2020-03-13          GM0074            Heerenveen        0       
## 10 2020-03-13          GM0080            Leeuwarden        0       
## # … with 4,990 more rows
```

```
Hos_day <- Hos_day %>%
  mutate(., Date_of_publication = Date_of_statistics) %>%
   filter(Date_of_publication >= "2020-03-13") %>%
  select(., 
         "Municipality_code",
         "Hospital_admission") %>%
  head(., 5000)

Hos_day
```

Giving:

```
## # A tibble: 5,000 x 2
##    Municipality_code Hospital_admission
##    <chr>             <chr>             
##  1 GM0014            0                 
##  2 GM0034            0                 
##  3 GM0037            0                 
##  4 GM0047            0                 
##  5 GM0050            0                 
##  6 GM0059            0                 
##  7 GM0060            0                 
##  8 GM0072            0                 
##  9 GM0074            0                 
## 10 GM0080            0                 
## # … with 4,990 more rows
```

## Joining dataframes

** Here is where it goes wrong **

```
Joined <- Number_day %>% left_join(Hos_day, by = 'Municipality_code')
```

Giving:

```
## # A tibble: 72,760 x 5
##    Date_of_publicat… Municipality_co… Municipality_na… Deceased Hospital_admiss…
##    <chr>             <chr>            <chr>            <chr>    <chr>           
##  1 2020-03-13        GM0014           Groningen        0        0               
##  2 2020-03-13        GM0014           Groningen        0        0               
##  3 2020-03-13        GM0014           Groningen        0        0               
##  4 2020-03-13        GM0014           Groningen        0        0               
##  5 2020-03-13        GM0014           Groningen        0        1               
##  6 2020-03-13        GM0014           Groningen        0        0               
##  7 2020-03-13        GM0014           Groningen        0        0               
##  8 2020-03-13        GM0014           Groningen        0        0               
##  9 2020-03-13        GM0014           Groningen        0        0               
## 10 2020-03-13        GM0014           Groningen        0        0               
## # … with 72,750 more rows
```

All of a sudden there are +- 73K rows: 15 (will be more with more data) value inputs of hospital admissions get tagged to 1 date.  So indeed 2020-03-17 corresponds to 1. From inspecting the data, i can validate that the input for `Hospital_admissions` is 15 rows. So 2020-03-27 is where "Groningen" stops and at 2020-03-38 another Muni starts with the admission values. The problem is thus getting the date correct (1:1 to a hospital value) and thus remove the many values stuck to them rn.

I tried to remedy this, but I can't find a way. Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Do you have 5000 **unique** Municipality_code in the "Hos_day" data frame?  I suspect you have duplicated values and each one of those are being joined to your original data frame.

Comment: The easiest way to make it clear would probably be to take a look at the csv. But i am going to try! The Municipality_code's ranges from GM0014-GM1991 (having missing codes in between). Each row is a date, lets say the date is 2020-02-27, then for each municipality theres 1 row for input on the death toll/ hospital admissions. So in reality each day adds, i believe +- 350 rows, and so on until you get like 280K rows. SO, yes each municipality has its own code, but NO it's not unique, as in just popping up once in the Municipality_code column.

Comment: I believe you need to join on both the Municipality_code and the date columns in order to get a 1 to 1 relationship between "Hos_day" and "Number_day"

Comment: That indeed solved it, I wanted to do this from the start, but did not, because the assignment says "Joint the two data sets on the regions". Maybe this realisation, that you need to join on two, is part of the assignment, who knows...  Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

Select `Date_of_publication` in `Hos_day`

```
Hos_day <- Hos_day %>%
  mutate(., Date_of_publication = Date_of_statistics) %>%
   filter(Date_of_publication >= "2020-03-13") %>%
  select(., "Date_of_publication", 
         "Municipality_code",
         "Hospital_admission") %>%
  head(., 5000)
```

Join on both the `Municipality_code` and the `Date_of_publication`

```
Joined <- Number_day %>% 
left_join(Hos_day, by = 
c('Municipality_code',
 'Date_of_publication'))
```